# Calculating probability of an event while taking prior attempts into account

Tags: probability

First, some context.  I have a turn-based strategy game where pieces on a board can attack other pieces.  Every attack has a percentage chance of success or failure.  This percentage can vary.  Using normal RNG techniques, this can result in unbalanced "luck" where one player succeeds more often and under less likely conditions than the other player.

There are multiple ways to improve the balance of "luck" in this game, but the one I'm looking at right now is to boost or reduce the percentage chance of the next attempt based on prior attempts.  This is one way to allow a player to more reliably expect the next attempt to succeed after a string of failures.

In my research, I looked up coin flips, e.g. "What are the odds of getting heads at least once in 3 tries".  I found a formula for calculating that, which looks like this:
$odds = 1 - 0.5^3 = 0.875$

So, I'm not sure how to apply that to my context.  But, perhaps this example will help you understand what I'm after.  In short, I know that the chances of getting heads on the 6th try is 50% even after flipping a coin 5 times and getting T, T, H, T, and H.  But I want to slightly boost those chances based on the fact that I already flipped slightly more tails than heads previously (or reduce those chances if the reverse is true).  Also, in my context, the chances aren't always 50/50 like coins.  So I need some sort of formula where I can input prior attempt percentages to arrive at an adjusted percentage for the next attempt.

So here's some example input that should be a good test for the formula.  Even if I have 2 failed attacks and 1 successful attack, the odds of success will still be REDUCED for the next attack because the success was less likely than the 2 failures combined.  Here they are in order:

- 1st attempt: 10% chance of success, but it succeeded
- 2nd attempt: 20% chance of success, but it failed
- 3rd attempt: 25% chance of success, but it failed
- 4th attempt: 50% chance of success on an individual basis, but what are the odds on an aggregate basis?

**Final Comments:**

1. I don't expect the order of prior attacks to matter when computing the aggregate odds for the next.  But I am interested in seeing a counter argument and formula.
2. I expect we only need to input "individual" percentages (as opposed to "aggregate" percentages) for prior attacks when computing the aggregate percentage for the next.  But, again, I am interested in seeing a counter argument and formula.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: I fixed the formula per your suggestion.  Thanks @saulspatz!

Comment: @pongstylin If I understand correctly, you want the percentage of success to be altered by some form of "luck correction", but the actual value of it depends on other things too. For example, in the example you give, how did you decide on $10\rightarrow20\rightarrow25\rightarrow50$?

Comment: @stochastic13 The 10, 20, 25, 50 values (taking success and failure into account) are input for the formula.  They are mostly arbitrarily selected, but was crafted to ensure that despite 2 prior attack failures, the next one has a greater chance of failure than success (In other words, a penalty is applied to the base 50% chance to arrive at a less than 50% chance for the 4th attempt).

Comment: @stochastic13 If it helps to understand what I'm after, I just don't know how to calculate the probability of a flipping 4 differently weighted coins and getting heads, tails, tails, and heads again where the coin weights are 10/90, 20/80, 25/75, 50/50 for getting heads/tails respectively.  Once I am able to calculate that value (a value I expect to be less than 50%), I can probably figure out how to multiply it against the base 50% chance of the 4th event to skew it in the right direction.

Comment: @stochastic13 In fact, I might just replace the base percentage with the overall probability percentage since it factors in the base percentage already.  My whole wordy question might be summed up as I don't know how to calculate probability of N events with different individual weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be possible to come up with multiple different "correction" strategies since the requirements are too general for now.

#### Setup

Assume $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ denotes the time step. You start at $t=1$. The "base" probability of success at the time step $t$ is $p_t$ without any correction and the corrected version is $\hat p_t$. Let $X_t \in \{0, 1\}$ denote the outcome at time $t$, where $1$ is a success.

#### Probability of success

If you do not do any adjustment, the probability of succeeding at time step $t$ is $p_t$. You can write the probability of the outcome (whichever outcome you get) at time step $t$ to be $X_tp_t + (1-X_t)(1-p_t)$ which you can check gives you the correct answer irrespective of what $X_t$ is.

At time step $t$, the probability of exactly getting the sequence $X_1, X_2, ... , X_t$ (eg: $1, 0, 0, ... 1$) is (assuming independent flips) $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{t}\left(X_ip_i+(1-X_i)(1-p_i)\right)$. But since this is specific to a given order of outcomes, the probability monotonically decreases as $t$ increases (i.e. the number of possible sequences increase) as long as $p < 1$. At this stage, it is unclear how you would construct a probability question to ask some version of "how lucky the person was". You can try asking the probability of being as "lucky" as the person was or greater by asking the probability of getting as many successes the person got or more if you did not have varying $p$. This formulation for a time-dependent probability without a simple time-equation will require you to iterate over many different permutations (depending on how you define lucky) and might not be the best motivated question in your case anyway.

#### Considerations

Even in the above strategy, once you do come up with a "correction", it is difficult to decide whether you should use the uncorrected $p_t$ or the corrected version $\hat p_t$ to calculate future corrections. The former seems to be slightly better motivated since your aim is to find out how "lucky" the player has been in comparison to the base probabilities.

#### Easier Strategy

Since you only need a correction which roughly translates to the inverse of how lucky the person was, here is one way to do it. You find the series $E[X_1], E[X_2], ... , E[X_t]$ and then you "subtract" the sequence you obtained from it to obtain the sequence of deviations $p_1 - X_1, p_2 - X_2, ..., p_t - X_t$ (since $E[x_i]=p_i$, you can replace the former with the latter). This represents how much did the player deviate from the "expected" mean, negative deviation meaning the player was overly lucky. You can sum all the entries, and the sign of the sum tells you if the player was overly unsuccessful or overly successful. You can create a correction by adding a small portion of this sum to the next probability $p_{t+1}$. Ideally, you should also divide by the standard deviations to get a "normalized" version of the deviation from the mean of the individual sum elements. Here's one possible formula for the correction factor $c$ and some arbitrary small constant $a$.

$$c_{t+1} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{t}\frac{p_i - X_i}{\sqrt{p_i(1-p_i)}}$$
$$\hat p_{t+1} = p_{t+1} + ac_{t+1}$$

(taking measures to keep $\hat p_{t+1}$bounded between $0$ and $1$) Selection of $a$ is in essence arbitrary, but here is a suggestion of how to come up with a value. You can simply set $a=\sqrt{p_{t+1}(1-p_{t+1})}$ which is the standard deviation of the $t+1$th step. You can keep a factor of $0<x \leq 1$ depending on how strict you want the correction to be.

#### Does this fulfill your requirements?

You can check out that this works for your given example. Note that the order of the successes do matter in this strategy. I am not sure what you mean by individual vs aggregate in the second point.

There are many specific properties of such a formula, and whether they suit you or some other suggestion might suit you better, depends on the details of the situation. From the broad phrasing of the question, I am assuming that an intuitively appeasing correction might work without the need of some specific statistical properties. You can try titrating the $a$ or $x$ to your needs, or try modifying the formula by taking the squared deviation from the mean divided by the variance, or forget the denominator entirely. All of these would change the statistical properties and may be better or worse (or equivalent) for your case.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response.  It will require some study on my part to fully grasp what you are saying since I am not a mathematician.  With that said, some things resonated such that I think you are on the right path.  While I study, please update your answer based on my explanation of the terms "individual" and "aggregate".  They are synonymous with "uncorrected" and "corrected" percentages, respectively, to use your terminology.

Comment: @pongstylin I reformatted some parts in the answer. As for "individual/aggregate", the motivation behind why you are calling that is unclear to me. "Aggregate" seems a bit understandable as the percentage resulting from some form of correction due to past stats, but why "individual"?

Comment: The terms individual and aggregate were chosen to differentiate between two different percentages much like you did with uncorrected and corrected.  The uncorrected percentage is associated with a single/individual attack.  The corrected percentage is derived from many/aggregate attacks.

Comment: In case it isn't now clear, what you said in the "Considerations" block is essentially what I said in the 2nd "Final Comment".  We both expect uncorrected percentages from prior attacks to be the best input for the formula.

Comment: I finished studying your post.  The first section that multiplies multiple percentages together doesn't help me at all, although it does provide a nifty formula for extracting the percentage associated with success vs failure.  The easier strategy, with some tuning, could solve the problem, but not in a way that resembles calculating coin flip probabilities.  I wanted something less fiddly / arbitrary.  I think my question was stated poorly so I'll accept your answer and create a new question.